# Error C2677: binary '*': no global operator found

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Sorry for asking a similar question that has been asked before, but I wasn't able to understand the answers.

Header file

```
    float Dot(const Point& other) const;
```

CPP

```
Point Point::operator*(float operand) const
{
    return Point(mX * operand, mY * operand);
}
```

and I am getting   Error C2677: binary '*': no global operator found

what is the problem??

Comment: What does `Dot` have to do with `Point::operator*`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You have Dot and Point, how do they relate?  And where is mX and mY coming from?

Comment: Also, that's only part of the error message.

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete (compilable) source code snippet that exhibits this issue. You can post it to e.g. coliru.stacked-crooked.com or godbolt.org or similar.

Comment: Na, those online compilers are nice, but SO guidelines require the relevant info inline in the question. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: what are `mX` and `mY`? How `Dot` is related to `operator*`? This is a lot confusing...

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented `operator*` in the cpp file but in the header file you only declared a simple `Dot` function.

You either move the operator* inline in the header file or you add a declaration for it in the header file, ie:

```
Class Point {
[...]
    Point operator*( float operand ) const {
        return Point( mX * operand, mY * operand) );
    } 
};
```

That operator defined that way is a *member operator* because you have declared inside the class itself. You might also want to add a *global operator*, for example a comparison operator, which you will place *outside* your class declaration, for example:

```
Class Point {
[...]
    Point operator*( float operand ) const {
        return Point( mX * operand, mY * operand) );
    } 
};

bool operator==(const Point& left, const Point& right) 
{
    return left.value == right.value;
};
```

**Final thought:**

So to recap the error you've got it most probably means that you didnt' declare the `operator*` as global operator as shown above. Also I think you might confusing a dot product with a multiplication, (operator*), which held two very different results, also notice one is a scalar operation (in any dimension), the other is a Point, in this case, two dimension.